# document.getElementById().src could not present images under Jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question of `document.getElementById().src` under jQuery Template.

Firstly I created an array of 5 pictures(only the first element was depicted) as showed below:

```
var Image = function(src){
    this.src = src;
}

var images = [];
images[0] = new Image("images/hedgehog.jpg");
```

Then I created a function which includes passing the src of the array to an ID(only relevant code was depicted):

```
document.getElementById("theQ").src = images[0].src;
```

The final part is the place expected to present the picture, but it didn't work:

```
<p style="text-align:center;" id="theQ"></p>
```

The navigation is correct as I could see the picture when I hover on the URL in text editor. Thank you for the help!

Comment: _but it didn't work_: Please specify what exactly didn't work. Did you observe the network request for this image? Does it succeed? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Paragraphs don’t have src as an attribute.  You want to append the image to the <p> element.

Comment: Hello @31piy. I expect to display a image at the paragraph where the id "theQ" is located. However there was not a image when I executed. I used bracket as my text editor. I think there are no problems of network.

Comment: Hi @SimianAngel, probably I have to recheck the property of <p> and try to avoid using it here. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Why would a paragraph element have a src attribute? Setting src to a paragraph does nothing since it does not have a src property. It is like adding a steering wheel to a box, it is not going to make it into a car. Use need to an image, not a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

A paragraph is not an image. You can't attach a source to it. And it makes no sense to shadow the image constructor, just use the [native one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image):

```
const img = new Image();
img.src = "images/hedgehog.jpg";
```

Now you can easily append that image to the dom:

```
document.getElementById("theQ").appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonas W. Now I could see the picture after execution! I get to know that the image couldn't be attached to <p>.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use `jQuery` in your template.

```js
var Image = function(src){
    this.src = src;
}

var images = [];
images[0] = new Image("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/woman-wearing-yellow-floral-top-116695890.jpg");
$("#theQ").append("<img src=\""+images[0].src+"\" width=\"150\" />");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="text-align:center;" id="theQ"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter Darmins! I d have a try and do some search for that.